# Selenium - wait several minutes before click a button

Tags: selenium, ui-automation

I want to wait several mins after the page is loaded and then click some button.
Tried to do something like this:

```
@And("^Wait for \"([^\"]*)\" minutes$")
    public void waitForMintues(long time){
         //Thread.sleep() or webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(time, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
         //click some button
    }
```

But it does not work. The tests still execute without waiting certain minutes. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Is `Thread.Sleep()` commented out here?

If you want to always wait a few minutes, you need to use the explicit wait — `Thread.Sleep(50000));` or `Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));`

Implicit wait is usually used in the context of waiting for an element to exist. But since you always want to wait a few minutes, you should use explicit wait.

Comment: Did you remove `//` that was preceding the `Thread.Sleep` call? Can you set a breakpoint on that line of code and verify if it is being reached?

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions` to achieve then utilize `.elementToBeClickable` method, it will wait first then click.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("...."))).click();
```

Following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

`10` is timeout in seconds, and try change `By.xpath("....")` with the your locator.

[Docs](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)